# Discord.js - ReferenceError: message is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I was watching a tutorial on how to make a command handler for discord.js. I typed the same thing as in the video (https://youtu.be/aqJydd30xmE?t=713) but somehow I get the error message "ReferenceError: message is not defined"

This is my Code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json");
const colors = require("../colors.json")

module.exports.run = async (bot, mssage, args) => {
    let sEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(colors.green)
        .setTitle("Server Info")
        .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL)
        .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Info`, message.guild.iconURL)
        .addField("**Server Name:**", `${message.guild.name}`, true)
        .addField("**Server Owner:**", `${message.guild.owner}`, true)
        .addField("**Mitglieder:**", `${message.guild.memberCount}`, true)
        .addField("**Rollen:**", `${message.guild.roles.size}`, true)
        .setFooter(`CrafterBot`, bot.user.displayAvatarURL);
        message.channel.send({embed: sEmbed});
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "serverinfo",
    aliases: ["si", "ServerInfo", "ServerDesc", "serverdesc"]
}
```

Comment: `I typed the same thing` No you didn't. `mssage` and `message` are different things.

Comment: oof I didnt see my typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You type `mssage` and your trying to use as `message`

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, mssage, args) => {
```

And here you trying to use `message`

```
.setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL)
```